# Vue3 / Vuex changing store state doesn't update computed prop

Tags: python, django, vue.js, fetch, vuex

I work on a ecommerce website build with Vue.js 3 and Django. Currently facing some issues with the cart functionality. I want to update the amount of items inside the cart without reloading the page, so just updating the cart component. For this I set up a Vue app which looks like this:

Vue.js

```
   <li class="nav-item" id="navbar-app">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Cart ([[ numItems ]])</a>
   </li>
...js
    const store = {
        state: {
            numItems: {{ cart.get_cart_length }}
        },
        mutations: {
            increment(state, quantity) {
                console.log(quantity)
                state.numItems += quantity
            }
        }
    }
    const Navbarapp = {
        delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
        store: store,
        computed: {
            numItems() {
                let cart_items = store.state.numItems
                return cart_items
            }
        }
    }
    Vue.createApp(Navbarapp).use(store).mount('#navbar-app')
```

> The get_cart_length function just queries the amount of items: cart.py
>
> def get_cart_length(self):
> return sum(int(item['quantity']) for item in self.cart.values())

If a user adds an item to the cart a fetch function is running. Everything works fine if I update the page I get correct results and correct items so this is not the problem. I tried to trigger the store that the computed prop `numItems` will update like this:
(inside the fetch function)

```
...
.then((res) => {
   this.store.commit('increment', 1)
})
...
```

**this throws an error**: **`Cannot read property 'commit' of undefined`**

if i refresh the page after adding an item the correct amount is displayed but i want the component to update without refreshing the page. i tried but haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your store like this:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({ // this line changed ...
  state: {
      numItems: {{ cart.get_cart_length }}
  },
  mutations: {
      increment(state, quantity) {
          console.log(quantity)
          state.numItems += quantity
      }
  }
});  // and this line changed ...
```

and for call your mutation you can use `store` without `this` keyword (like your computed property)

```
store.commit('increment', 1)
```

or with this keyword:

```
this.$store.commit('increment', 1)
```

Comment: I tried this now I'm getting error "Vue.mixin is not a function". I imported vuex.js version 3.6.2 and vue.global.min.js version 3.0.11

Comment: you can't use `Vuex3` for `Vue3` you should use `vuex4` for `Vue3` : https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/installation.html

Comment: Oh ok, didnt know that. Now yours solution works :) thaanks for your help!